# Is it possible for EF Core 3.0 to use FromSql inside ModelBuilder rather than on DbSet<>

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am mapping EF onto a legacy DB, and at the moment have to create views in the legacy DB to do that.

Rather than modify the existing schema at all, I'd like to use the new `HasNoKey` existing `FromSql` methods to map my entities onto SQL defined within my application.

i.e.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Names>(entity =>
  {
    entity.HasNoKey();
    entity.FromSql("{SELECT_STATEMENT_FROM_MY_VIEW}");
    ... OR ...
    entity.ToView("{SELECT_STATEMENT_FROM_MY_VIEW_NOT_VIEW_NAME}")
  });

}
```

I'm thinking I could do this in the new `IInterceptor` but this feels a bit hacky to me.

Comment: Why do you want to do that at all, instead of specifying the column names in the entity itself? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve and why don't you use views if the queries are complex? They won't get *less* complex if you move them to code. They'll get a *lot* harder to optimize or modify though

Comment: It is a legacy DB which requires a non-trivial view to map columns to entities. I need a view, stored proc or piece of raw SQL. I have already explained I am  using views but I do not want to modify schema for legacy DB and wish to specify the select involved in the view in my model creation instead.

Comment: So what's the problem? Why do you want to put the view statement in code? You can map entities to views. It's not legacy databases that need view, any complex database needs them

Comment: No, it's not clear. Do you want to map to views or not? Are you asking whether you can avoid the call to `ToView()` shown [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types#example)? A view isn't just a SELECT statement, it's a database object with metadata. EF uses that metadata in the mappings to *create* queries. Why not add methods to your context that return the IQueryable<> generated from specific [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) calls? Eg `public IQueryable<Name> Names => this.FromSql(...);`

Comment: This isn't nitpicking by the way. You need to know why you want this feature, or whether you can use alternatives. Is there something that `FromRawSql` doesn't provide but DbSet<T> does? You can look into EF Core's source on Github to see how the view is used and how to work around it.

Comment: I want to map SQL that would otherwise be in views that would require schema modifications which I don't want to make - it really is that simple.

Comment: no it's not. That's what you said from the start and repeating it doesn't help at all. Why don't you use `FromRawSql`? You don't need to specify `ToView()` when you specify the SQL statement itself. That's how query types (now called keyless types) were meant to be used from the start. You can type the entire query in `FromRawSql` just as you asked

Comment: *sigh* ...ok. so if I use `FromRawSql`, for multiple entities that are related to each other can I also use the `Include()` keyword to optionally include child entities that are also mapped with `FromRawSql` ?

Comment: They can only appear in reference navigation properties (ie single items) of regular entities. The limitations are explained in [Keyless entity type characteristics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types#keyless-entity-types-characteristics) and have nothing to do with `ToView()` or `FromRawSql`.

Comment: So I've answered your question as to why I can't use `FromRawSql` - now let's see if someone can answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: No you haven't. You answered why you can't use Keyless Entities **at all**. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve and why did you look to keyless entities? Most likely the *actual* problem has a very different solution

Comment: Long story short, if you want relations, you have to remove `entity.HasNoKey();`

Comment: Ok. So if I remove `HasNoKey` can I then have relations and not need to create schema, in a similar way to how I can with when I create views in the DB?

Comment: Sorry, I have a job too. Please update the question itself explaining the actual problem, what you tried to solve it and give an actual example that people can test. If you can do that using a common schema, eg the Blogs/Posts schema, it would be easier for people to come up with solutions

Comment: The answer to my question is "no" as far as I can see.... which is why I asked this question, in case someone has a solution :) but thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did in the end use `IInterceptor` - basically it makes the assumption that in T-SQL, a View is always equivalent (for read-only purposes) to a select and can therefore be directly substituted.

This is the core extensions class that generates registers an interceptor singleton and tracks SQL to substitute by inserting a guid-based "mock" table name using the existing `ToView`. Then before running the command text it replaces the non-existent view with the associated SQL:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    private static readonly SqlViewInterceptor SqlViewInterceptorSingleton = new SqlViewInterceptor();

    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder AddViewToSqlInterceptor(
        this DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilder)
    {
        dbContextOptionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(SqlViewInterceptorSingleton);
        return dbContextOptionsBuilder;
    }

    public static EntityTypeBuilder<T> ToSqlView<T>(this EntityTypeBuilder<T> entityTypeBuilder, string sql)
        where T : class
    {
        return entityTypeBuilder.ToView(SqlViewInterceptorSingleton.RegisterSqlForView(sql));
    }

    private class SqlViewInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> MockTablesToSql = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
        {
            foreach (var mockTable in MockTablesToSql.Keys)
            {
                command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace(mockTable, MockTablesToSql[mockTable]);
            }

            return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
        }

        public string RegisterSqlForView(string viewSql)
        {
            var mockTableName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            MockTablesToSql.TryAdd($"[{mockTableName}]", $"({viewSql})");
            return mockTableName;
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can use a standard `DbContext` in  the normal way - must ensure that the interceptor is registered in the `OnConfiguring` method, and can then use the `AddViewToSql` extension to register View equivalent read-only SQL:

```
public class LegacyDbContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer("data source=.\\sql2017; database=Test; integrated security=true")
            .AddViewToSqlInterceptor();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Arbitrary SQL for parent
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<LegacyEntity>()
            .ToSqlView("SELECT CASE LegacyId WHEN 100 THEN 1 ELSE LegacyId END LegacyId FROM LegacyTable");

        // Arbitrary SQL for child
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<LegacyChild>()
            .ToSqlView("SELECT LegacyParentId LegacyEntityLegacyId, LegacyChildId FROM LegacyChild");
    }

    public DbSet<LegacyEntity> LegacyEntities { get; set; }
}

public class LegacyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int LegacyId { get; set; }

    public IList<LegacyChild> Children { get; set;  }
}

public class LegacyChild
{
    public int LegacyChildId { get; set; }
}
```

And here are a few unit tests I wrote to confirm that (for simple cases at least) the behaviour is as expected - EF will still restrict via `WHERE` clauses and aggregate via `SUM` in SQL, and it will allow `Include` to work for parent-child relationships...

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestDbContext
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        using var ctx = new LegacyDbContext();
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE LegacyTable;");
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE LegacyChild;");
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"INSERT INTO LegacyTable (LegacyId) VALUES ({i});");
            ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"INSERT INTO LegacyChild (LegacyParentId, LegacyChildId) VALUES ({i}, {i * 2});");
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestLegacyView()
    {
        using var ctx = new LegacyDbContext();
        var filteredRows = ctx.LegacyEntities.Where(x=>x.LegacyId <= 5).ToArray();
        Assert.That(filteredRows.Length, Is.EqualTo(5));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestLegacyViewScalar()
    {
        using var ctx = new LegacyDbContext();
        var filteredRows = ctx.LegacyEntities.Where(x=>x.LegacyId <= 5).Sum(x=>x.LegacyId);
        Assert.That(filteredRows, Is.EqualTo(15));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestLegacyChild()
    {
        using var ctx = new LegacyDbContext();
        var filteredRows = ctx.LegacyEntities
            .Include(x=>x.Children)
            .Where(x => x.LegacyId <= 5)
            .ToArray()
            .Sum(x => x.Children.Sum(c=>c.LegacyChildId));

        Assert.That(filteredRows, Is.EqualTo(30));
    }
}
```